# Can't update my app on iTunes Connection

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I want to update my app on iTunes Connect, and every thing is ok. Apple send me an E-mail:

```
Dear xxxx.,

The following build has completed processing:

Platform: iOS
App Name: xxx
Build Number: 2.5.6
Version Number: 2.5
App SKU: xxxx
App Apple ID: xxxx
You can now use this build for TestFlight testing or submit it to the App Store.

If you have any questions regarding your app, click Contact Us in iTunes Connect.

Regards,

The App Store team
```

but i cannot find the "+" after build version.  so i cannot add my new build version.  And i called the Telephone Support, but there's nobody answer.

What can i do?

Comment: - Change your build version (what ever you want, recomment new = old+1)
- Submit your build normally, TestFlight will manager your all builds

Comment: @QuocNguyen i did, and TestFlight shows 'prepare to test',  And i want to publish my app at once. But there's no '+' button to add my new build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a protocol called `Paid Applications`,  and i didn't changed anything. just open the protocol and click `request` button, and it worked. Now i can publish my new app.